# Linux - manipulating the columns of two text files

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two text files in this format:

File-1:

```
Class    Pos    Ref    Alt    Raw_score    Actual_Score
1        50203  Y      E      -0.00254     3.298 
5        6357   G      V       1.358       10.685 
2        87521  A      H       0.6587      6.3354
```

File-2:

```
Class    Pos    Ref    Alt     Info 
5        6357   G      V       ACT/wo%%$2.25;56842;ALT 
11       25684  H      A       GEP/hq#$..25;69875;Trans 
3        258    G      L       KPD/ng?~88q68;8954;Inter
```

If the `initial four columns` of `File-1` are matching with `initial four columns` of `File-2`, then put the words `Raw_score` and `Actual_score` and their `values` at the end of matching line, separated with `;` sign, as:

Output:

```
5        6357   G      V       ACT/wo%%$2.25;56842;ALT;Raw_score=1.358;Actual_score=10.685
```

Comment: You probably want to read about `join`, and also `awk` and `sort`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining Multiple Fields Using Unix Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619562/joining-multiple-fields-using-unix-join)

Comment: Yups, but joining pattern is different in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{k=$1FS$2FS$3FS$4}NR==FNR{if(NR>1)a[k]=";"b"="$5";"c"="$6;else{a[k]="";b=$5;c=$6}next}k in a{print $0a[k]}' file1 file2
Class    Pos    Ref    Alt     Info
5        6357   G      V       ACT/wo%%$2.25;56842;ALT;Raw_score=1.358;Actual_Score=10.685
```

If you don't understand that script then read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and modify the script to include blank chars, newlines, indenting, meaningful variable names, etc. to make it clearer - doing that will help you learn the language.