# Joining columns matching on multiple fields with non-equal keys between files using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, join, awk

I know similar questions have been asked before (e.g. [Joining multiple fields in text files on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619562/joining-multiple-fields-in-text-files-on-unix)) but I can't seem to find a solution for my specific problem.

My files are structured as follows (col1=ID, col2=time increment, col3=data):

```
head file1
14.000119    0       yes
14.000119    69      yes
14.000119    168     no
14.000119    259
14.000119    431
14.000119    888     yes
```

```
head file2
14.000119    0       no
14.000119    70      no
14.000119    169     yes
14.000119    262
14.000119    456
14.000119    525
```

My goal is to join these two files based on ID first and Time second. However, non-equal values of Time must also be added, and the data column (col3) must be placed in the correct column in the output file.

Desired output:

```
14.000119    0      yes    no    
14.000119    69     yes
14.000119    70            no
14.000119    168    no    
14.000119    169           yes
14.000119    259
14.000119    262
14.000119    431
14.000119    456
14.000119    525
14.000119    888    yes
```

Columns are tab seperated. I know there is a solution with either awk or join but I can't seem to get it right. The closest I've come was using

```
awk -F\\t '{
o1=$1;o2=$2
$1=$2="";gsub("\t","")
_[o1 FS o2]=_[o1 FS o2] FS $0
} END {
for(i in _) print i,_[i]
}' file1 file2 | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -n
```

Which gave me:

```
14.000119       0         yes      no
14.000119       69        yes
14.000119       70        no
14.000119       168       no
14.000119       169       yes
14.000119       259
14.000119       262
14.000119       431
14.000119       456
14.000119       525
14.000119       888       yes
```

But as you can see, the data values only get filled in the correct column (4th for file2) if the value for the same key in file1 is non-empty.

Comment: You should have provided more than 1 ID in your example if you can have more than 1 in your real data and included cases where a given ID only appears in file1 or only appears in file2. Never name a variable `_` btw - that's even less useful wrt understanding what the variable represents than naming it a single letter!

Comment: The variables are obviously not named _ in the real file, and having more or less ID's doesn't contribute to the nature of the problem since the data is sorted on the first column anyway. Thank you for your answer

Comment: It;s not obvious at all. Why rename a variable from something meaningful to `_` to post in a question where you want to make your script as easy as possible for others to understand so they can help you with it? Having more IDs makes it a far different problem than having 1 ID with various ways you might want to handle an ID that only appears in 1 file. For one example, in my answer I assumed you want all the IDs from both files to appear in numerical order but you might want some ignored, or the ones that are unique to 1 file to appear at the start or the end or something else. You're welcome

Comment: The way to show that your problem is solved is to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark. (But now I see the comments on your answer that you know this.) Please don't edit "solved" into your question. Please don't add EDITs/UPDATEs, just edit make a post the best it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using join and some workarounds!

```
join -j1 -a 1 -a 2 -e '' -o '0,1.4,2.4' -t $'\t' 
<(<file1 awk -F\\t '{print $1"-"$2 "\t" $0}' | sort -k1,1) 
<(<file2 awk -F\\t '{print $1"-"$2 "\t" $0}' | sort -k1,1) 
| sed 's/-/\t/g' | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -n
```

Explanation:
`-j1`: joins on the first field
`-a 1 -a 2`: also print unpairable lines from both files
`-e ''`: fill in blanks with empty fields
`-o 0,1.4,2.4`: output the first field, and 4th of file 1 and file 2
`-t $'\t'`: tab seperated
`<(<file1 ...)`print the first two columns with a '-' in between instead of a tab, to 'condense' the first two columns into one (join only works on *one* column)
`sed 's/-/\t/g'`: revert the dash back to a tab
`sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -n`: Now that the output contains 4 columns again, sort on the first and second

Comment: can you accept this answer (yes, your own answer), that way it is even more clear that the question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, but there is a 2 day waiting period. Will do it after that time has passed

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ vals[$1][$2][ARGIND] = $3 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (id in vals) {
        for (time in vals[id]) {
            print id, time, vals[id][time][1], vals[id][time][2]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
14.000119       0       yes     no
14.000119       69      yes
14.000119       70              no
14.000119       168     no
14.000119       169             yes
14.000119       259
14.000119       262
14.000119       431
14.000119       456
14.000119       525
14.000119       888     yes
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` and a little help of `sort`, how about:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==FNR {a[$1"\t"$2] = $3; next}
    {a[$1"\t"$2] ? a[$1"\t"$2] = a[$1"\t"$2]"\t"$3 : a[$1"\t"$2] = "\t"$3}
    END {for (i in a) print i"\t"a[i]}
' file1 file2 | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n
```

Result:

```
14.000119       0       yes     no
14.000119       69      yes
14.000119       70              no
14.000119       168     no
14.000119       169             yes
14.000119       259
14.000119       262
14.000119       431
14.000119       456
14.000119       525
14.000119       888     yes
```